# Yii2 user identity authentication

Tags: php, yii, yii2-advanced-app

I have two projects on `yii2`

When I log in on one project using `yii2` authentication method

```
(Yii::$app->user->identity)
```

the other project also creates a login session.

My first project is user registration and second is seller registration.

On successful login as user`(User id is 21- Database id )` and when I open the
seller project. A login is also created automatically with the user id 21 from the seller table.

Comment: And what is the question?

Answer (score 0):

this could be because you enabled autoLoginLogin in your  projects and you're probably using the same identityCookie configurations. Check Your config files..

```
'components' => [
        'user' => [
            'identityClass' => 'common\models\User',
            'enableAutoLogin' => true,
            'identityCookie' => [
                'name' => '_frontendUser',//change this
            ]
        ],
```